# How to make Break debugger button in Code::Blocks actually work?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

I am trying to break the debugger in Code::Blocks 20.03 under Windows by pressing "Break debugger" button. I use gdb debugger. However, I can never pause the debugger on any line of my code. Otherwise, the debugger works correctly.

I tried to press "Break debugger" button during the execution of my program a few times. What I expected to happen is that the execution would pause on one of the lines of my code. But whenever I pressed it the execution would break in the following function:

In ntdll!DbgBreakPoint () (C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)

When I pressed "Next line" button, I got to the following:

In ntdll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin () (C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll)

When I pressed "Next line" button again, the execution continued and I didn't get to any line of my code. What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you try examining the call stack? You might also just be in the wrong thread, I'd guess there's a window somewhere to change threads

Comment: I expect teh debugger in Code::Blocks worked fine. The problem is your misunderstanding of what it does. Specifically when you press break does not mean it will stop inside your code. You will have to  walk the call stack to see your code.

Comment: @AlanBirtles thank you for your comment. I actually was in the wrong thread. I switched to the first thread in Debug->Debugging windows->Running threads and was able to get into my code.